# Python tkinter: Handling ButtonPress Events differently on/off buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter

**Question:** It seems that ButtonPress events on tkinter give the location of the click w/r to the top left corner of the window. However, when you click on a Button widget, a ButtonPress event occurs, but the x,y location values given are w/r to the top left corner of the Button. How can I get the ButtonPress event to occur at the location w/r to the top left corner of the window, not the button?

**Details:** I have a tkinter program that lets users draw on a picture (layout below), but only occurs below a certain `y` value. If you move the cursor below that threshold (aka below the picture and into an area that has instructions), no drawing functionality can occur. Drawing only occurs with clicks, so `<Button-1>` is bound to a class method that keeps track of where the click occurred and draws on the picture at that location:

`self.root.bind('<Button-1>', self.addDot)`

However, in the area that has instructions, there is an undo button. Clicking on it in theory should undo the last click's effect. Instead, if I click on it, it registers a `<ButtonPress>` event that has x and y values with respect to the top left corner of the *button*, not the *window*. I do not know how to differentiate when the x,y location of a button press occurs w/r to the window or the button, so the `self.addDot` function executes near the top left of the image. Everywhere else you click behaves as normal.

**One caveat** I have seen is that if I change the binding to be on the canvas, not the root, this strangely goes away and behaves as expected. Why is that?

**Layout:**

[image: Layout of screen]

Comment: Did you try bind on the image instead of `root`?

Comment: All the children of `root` will inherit the binding if it is bound on `root`.